# Convert 2016-12-28 14:14:00 UTC date time format to 12/06/2016 11:28 PM format in rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am  querying MySQL database and getting date time in **2016-12-28 14:14:00 UTC format.**

But I want my date time converted to the format like **12/06/2016 11:28 PM in rails.**

Comment: Use `strftime` method in ruby. http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Comment: You want to convert UTC to which time zone ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to get the format as below:

```
d = '2016-12-28 14:14:00 UTC'.to_time
d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%p')
```

Comment: d = '2016-12-28 14:14:00 UTC'.to_time ===> "2016-12-05 17:18:00 -0500" format, on running  d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%p') ===> 12/05/2016 17:18PM. But I would like to have it in 12/07/2016 12:28 AM format.

Comment: Can you answer the question asked by dp7 in comment. I don't know what timezone you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails project I usually create special file called `config/initializers/date_time_formats.rb`

And add to their predefined a time formats.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:human_with_12hours] = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'
```

Reload server and use it like this: `YOUR_DATE_VARIABLE.to_s(:human_with_12hours)`

You can create lot of time and date formats in this file.